# How do you debug through a compressed JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm using django-compress to shrink my JavaScript files. However, I am now having trouble debugging through it because everything is squished. I believe Stack Overflow use some kind of JavaScript compression too. How do you go about to debug through your JavaScript code on the live site or on your development machine with the code well formatted?

Firebug has all the code in one line which makes it hard to dig through.

Comment: You can un-minify the js in dev tools: http://devtoolsecrets.com/secret/debugging-debugging-minified-javascript.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple answer is you don't debug through a compressed file - you use an uncompressed version for development.

Comment: Also, if you are using a mix of code you have written as well as code from outside libraries, most libraries also provide uncompressed versions of their code that is helpful for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I see an answer has already been accepted, but I am adding a new answer since this is the first result I got on Google and think this new info may help someone.

Some browser DevTools now support Source Maps to map built javascript to is unbuild readable state.  You have to minify and/or combine the JS with a tool that supports creating Source Maps.  But if you do you can see the original code when debugging the minified/combined javascript.

Find more info here: 
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging#source-maps

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Google Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/), then there is a plugin that allows you access the unminified version of the code.  See the documentation on the [Inspector](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/inspector.html) and the source mapping feature.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

- Don't compress until you deploy to production
- Reload your source code **after** the compress code; it will write over the compressed code
- When it's worth the investment, I take compressed code and manually uncompress it